# GetAsyncKeyState Explanation required

Tags: c#, function, keylogger

I wanted to make a little keylogger using the console application and I stumbled across this source code on the web and I have trouble understanding it.

```
while(true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);

        if (keyState == -32767)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)i);
        }
    }
}
```

So from what I understand, keystate is basically a function which tells if a key is currently being pressed. Since we want to check if any of the 255 keyboard keys are being checked we need a for cycle. Correct me if I am wrong.

So if the key we are currently pressing is well... pressed, it will return some Value (Would like to know what value this is...maybe the keycode value? Correct me because I am sure I am wrong).

But the IF is the part where I have totally lost it. If my understanding is correct, then the write line will only happen if we get -32767 which is who knows what? And that is what I would like to know. Why is it -32767? How come it works even if we never get -32767, LMB is 1 for example...?

Comment: Read the Return Code section of the msdn page - if the high bit is set then the key is down, and if it was pressed since the last call, then the low bit is one - which corresponds to -32767 === 0x8001

Comment: @Petesh Your comment is worthy enough to be an answer if you also provide a link to the MSDN page :).

Comment: So, why in the world do you use code you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my understanding is correct, then the write line will only happen if we get -32767 which is who knows what?

The value of `-32767` (0x8001) is an important value. `GetAsyncKeyState` returns a `short`, which means it is the least significant bit (0) of the 16bit return value.

According to the docs:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. **If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.**
>   That means it is looking for a key press between calls.